# How do i pass an mongoose id to a middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

My goal is to pass a mongoose id to an express middleware, but seems like It is not possible from my perspective, I tried to pass in req.params.id, but it returns an error

```
var middleware = require('./middleware');

app.get('/hello/:id', middleware.testing(req.params.id), function(req, res) {
    // do something

})
```

Middleware

```
exports.testing = function(id) {
    // do something

}
```

Comment: how would solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the middleware in a wrong way. A middleware already has access to `req.params`. What you do is actually *calling* the middleware instead of passing it as a callback.

Use this code instead:

```
var middleware = require('./middleware');

app.get('/hello/:id', middleware.testing, function(req, res) {
    // do something
});
```

Middleware

```
exports.testing = function(req, res) {
    // do something with req.params.id
}
```